# iPad Partial Curl modal transition always curls to full screen

Tags: ipad

I'm using `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` to show a modal view in iPad.

```
modalViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[[self parentViewController] presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];
```

`self` is the right side view controller of my `SplitViewController`.

When I do this, the page is curled all the way to the top even though the size of the `view` of modalViewController is small. I only need it to curl a little so it would reveal ONLY the area taken by modalViewController. What I'm trying to do is something exactly like the iPad maps application settings.

I tried using all the `modalPresentationStyle` options for the modal view and I also tried setting the `modalPresentationStyle.view.frame` to a small `CGRect` but still couldn't get it to work.

Can anybody help on this...thanks in advance..

Comment: I'm actually having this exact same problem. I've tried different things but have not got it to work like the Maps app yet. Did you find a solution to it?

Comment: No luck. I gave up using this method and went with other modal types. Don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Just leave a clean space (No Controls or Images) in the top of your PresentedViewController, the Framework make the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to find a more optimal solution, but I've been able to get good results by making the modal (revealed) view the same size as the parent (curling) view.  iOS looks at the subviews to determine where to stop the curling and shows "just enough" of the subview to keep the subview pieces on-screen.